# What Could Be Causing MySQL To Crash On A Read Query?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, database, sql, database-administration

So I have a pretty large MySQL DB... 7 Gigs in Total size, 35 million URLs.

I was querying it (using SELECT queries only) quite fast the other day. My ubuntu froze/shutdown (that's a first!) and said something online the lines of "panic, reverting to text console" - but she was frozen solid.

Upon rebooting my computer. Every MySQL table in the DB was fine, except for the one I was reading from. It said "in use".

Any idea what could have caused this? Surely MySQL is smart enough to know when a SELECTion has finished?

EDIT: Could it be that I need to start running a standalone MySQL server? I mean... this one's at 100%cpu almost constantly between running my PHP script to access it and MySQL having to dig through such a large DB...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, yes, split the filesystem from the db.  Well, if your using MyISAM tables than mysql will do a row level lock on the select.  The reads should happen completely independent of each other and there shouldn't have been any problems. Is there any disk space issues or swap space issues?  You should be able to reset the table status through mysqladmin.

Also, what are you values for your buffer sizes? (look in my.cf) or in mysqladmin under variables.  That will give some insight into what might have happened.  And lastly was there anything in the /var/log/messages or mysqld log files?

Answer (score 0):

I'd almost suspect filesystem corruption. FSCK the filesystem? Anything in the logs leading up to the crash?

Comment: On second thought... I MIGHT have been running two queries at once, but even still... they would both have been select queries. I will check through the MySQL logs and let you know ASAP. Any other logs I should be checking?